# ¿Cómo pasar un struct de tipo puntero como parámetro?

Tags: c++

tengo el siguiente codigo el cual divide una cadena en diferentes partes, quiero pasar un puntero a estructura como parametro para reducir la cantidad de parametros, pero me manda error, como si el puntero no estubiera apuntando a nada, ¿alguien sabe como solucionarlo?
el formato es el siguiente:`1016833953 BAQUERO RUBIANO JUAN SEBASTIAN`

```
struct parameters{

    string cadena;
    string documento; 
    string primer_apellido; 
    string segundo_apellido; 
    string primer_nombre; 
    string segundo_nombre; 
    
};
 
struct parameters* parameters;

void cortar3(struct parameters* pr){

    pr->documento = pr->cadena.substr(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' '));
    pr->cadena.erase(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' ') + 1);

    pr->primer_apellido = pr->cadena.substr(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' '));
    pr->cadena.erase(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' ') + 1);

    pr->segundo_apellido = pr->cadena.substr(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' '));
    pr->cadena.erase(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' ') + 1);

    pr->primer_nombre = pr->cadena.substr(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' '));
    pr->cadena.erase(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' ') + 1);
}

void cortar4(struct parameters* pr){

    pr->documento = pr->cadena.substr(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' '));
    pr->cadena.erase(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' ') + 1);

    pr->primer_apellido = pr->cadena.substr(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' '));
    pr->cadena.erase(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' ') + 1);

    pr->segundo_apellido = pr->cadena.substr(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' '));
    pr->cadena.erase(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' ') + 1);

    pr->primer_nombre = pr->cadena.substr(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' '));
    pr->cadena.erase(0, pr->cadena.find_first_of(' ') + 1);

    pr->segundo_nombre = pr->cadena;

}

int main(){

    

    /*
    vector<string> documentos(n);
    vector<string> primeros_apellidos(n);
    vector<string> segundos_apellidos(n);
    vector<string> primeros_nombres(n);
    vector<string> segundos_nombres(n);
*/
    int espacios = 0;
    string cadena;
    
    
    cout<<"ingrese la cadena:"<<'\n';
    getline(cin,cadena);

    cout<<cadena<<endl;

    espacios = std::count(cadena.begin(), cadena.end(), ' ');

    if (espacios == 3)
    {
        cortar3(parameters);
    }
    else if (espacios == 4)
    {
        cortar4(parameters);
    }
    
    cout<<"espacios:"<<espacios<<'\n';
    cout<<parameters->documento<<'\n';
    cout<<parameters->primer_apellido<<'\n';
    cout<<parameters->segundo_apellido<<'\n';
    cout<<parameters->primer_nombre<<'\n';
    cout<<parameters->segundo_nombre<<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta ya tiene 1 voto de cierre por "debe ser más específica". Considera agregar más detalles sobre lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: @Christian, ya lo corregi

Comment: En C tendrías que escribir `struct parameters pr`. Pero en C++ solo `parameters pr`. Por cierto, en lugar de pasar un puntero sugiero que pases una referencia: `parameters &pr`. La ventaja es que no necesitas la flecha para acceder a sus miembros.

Comment: @Mateo, pero si necesito llamar muchas veces a esa funcion no seria mejor puntero ?

Comment: La única situación donde es mejor usar un puntero es cuando quieres reasignar la variable.

Comment: @Christian ya corregi la pregunta

Answer (score -1):

Para reducir el número de parámetros en una función, puedes usar una estructura (struct) en lugar de pasar muchos parámetros individuales. Una estructura es un tipo de dato que puede contener muchos campos diferentes, y puedes usarla para agrupar datos relacionados en un solo lugar.

Comment: ¿porque votaste la pregunta como negativa ?

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo el no fue, los usuarios con una reputación menor a 125 no pueden emitir votos en contra. Por otra parte los votos son anónimos y ni siquiera un moderador puede verlos.